# How to find world market index symbols in different brokers (i.e. TOS, RH)

Tags: trading, futures, brokerage, market-indexes

I use Thinkorswim to check on the E-Mini S&P 500 futures, 'ES20', but I also want to see the FTSE 100, CAC 40, AEX, Hang Seng, etc. But when I enter those names to the search field I get no results, or multiple mixed results. How can I find the world indices equivalent to the S&P 500 futures and be sure I am looking at the right symbol?

Comment: If not mistaken, TD Ameritrade only supports US instruments. You can always start a live chat with customer service within Thinkorswim to ask for help.

Comment: Their support senda me to a page that shows the data, but not the sumbols themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is no symbol standard anywhere for futures contracts, you'll just have to find the resources on whatever data platform you use.